# Horizontal scrolling in Adobe Animate AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, scroll, jquery-animate, adobe, mouseevent

Is there a way to catch horizontal scrolling in Adobe Animate AS3?
So far I have:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, function(e:MouseEvent){
    trace(e.delta);
});
```

...but that only fires on vertical scrolling and only gives me the vertical delta.

Comment: What kind of input device provides you with the ability to scroll horizontally?

Comment: Whats the problem? Use the vertical numbers (y axis) of mouse wheel to control horizontal (x) position of screen item... simples!

Comment: My Macbook trackpad does with two-finger scrolling. My code above catches the two-finger vertical scrolling.

Comment: @VC.One: I don't know what you mean by using the "vertical numbers". Please provide a code example.

Comment: `});`....? That looks weird. Should just be }

Comment: If it only fires on vertical scrolling, then what could you possibly mean by horizontal delta?

Comment: That's was a typo - I corrected horizontal to vertical. Obviously I'm looking for something like a horizontal delta.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is an old thread, and since no answers are given thus far, I am answering it for future readers.

Suppose you have a ScrollPane component in your stage and it displays a large image, then you can listen to horizontal scroll (Actually both scrolls) by listening to ScrollEvent like following:

```
import fl.containers.ScrollPane;
import fl.events.ScrollEvent;

var img: ScrollPane = new ScrollPane(...); // Create a scroll pane for scroll event
img.source = ImgClass; // A Bitmap class containing dummy image to scroll

this.addChild(img);

img.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, onScroll);

function onScroll(e: ScrollEvent) {
  if (e.direction === "horizontal") { // Trace only on horizontal scroll
    trace("Delta: " + e.delta);
    trace("Position: " + e.position);
  }
}
```